# How to read SMS from sim in dongle using JAVA

Tags: java, smslib

I am using following code to send sms from dongle.
Its sending Sucessfullly.
Now I want to read SIM sms or unread sms from dongle so plaese can any one tell me how to read that

following is the code to send sms

```
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway; 

...

private  String port = "COM4";          // Modem Port.
private  int bitRate = 9600;            // This is also optional. Leave as it is.
private  String modemName = "ZTE";      // This is optional.
private  String modemPin = "0000";      // Pin code if any have assigned to the modem.
private  String SMSC = "+919822078000"; // Message Center Number ex. Mobitel

...

SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", port, 9600, "InterCEL", "");
Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
Service.getInstance().startService();
// System.out.println("center number=" + gateway.getSmscNumber());
gateway.setSmscNumber(SMSC);
gateway.setOutbound(true); 

OutboundMessage o = new OutboundMessage(number, str);
gateway.sendMessage(o);
```

There is InboundMessage class which takes three parameters sunch as gateway, MemoryIndexNumber, SimMemoryLocation which I am unable to get so it returns null

```
InboundMessage n=new InboundMessage()
gateway.readMessage(n);
```

If there is any other way to read sms from SIM of dongle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read the messages currently in the SIM memory, you can just do

```
ArrayList<InboundMessage> msgList = new ArrayList<InboundMessage>();
Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, InboundMessage.MessageClasses.ALL);
for (InboundMessage im : msgList) {

}
```

But to do live detection of incoming messages, you need to implement org.smslib.IInboundMessageNotification

E.g.

```
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.IInboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Message.MessageTypes;

public class SMSInNotification implements IInboundMessageNotification
{   
    public void process(AGateway gateway, MessageTypes msgType, InboundMessage msg)
    {
        switch (msgType)
        {
            case INBOUND:
                System.out.println(">>> New Inbound message detected from " + "+" + msg.getOriginator() + " " + msg.getText());
                break;
            case STATUSREPORT:

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then run these before the line which starts the service with .startService()

```
gateway.setInbound(true);
Service.getInstance().setInboundMessageNotification(new SMSInNotification());
```

You can read more in the documentation on github
https://github.com/smslib/smslib-v3/tree/master/doc

Comment: Firstly Thanks now i am able to read the messages but notifiaction is not working i have done same think you said but i am not getting any output when i recieve the sms please can you tell me how to to again .    i have done the following way is it right                                         SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("", portname,9600, "InterCEL", "");gateway.setInbound(true);
Service.getInstance().setInboundMessageNotification(new SMSInNotification());
                 Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
                 Service.getInstance().startService();

Comment: I removed my own handling code from that notification class i posted. So it won't output anything. Did you add some handling code yourself?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clearer what I mean

Comment: I have also written same thing but it is not entering process function on receiving sms

Comment: Please can you increase your log4j level and give me some logs to look at?  The logging looks quite verbose so I think it will highlight the problem.

Comment: when i am sending sms from mobile to dongle sim then the notifiction class sholud get called automatically means it sholud enter process function but its not entering the process function

Comment: Yes it should. Please give logs. Maybe a misconfiguration on your end or a bug in the library.

Comment: I have never used logs how i will provide you the logs